# How to divide count(*) by count(*) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I am struggling to find the maximum value out of multiple rows from a count divided by a count. I am trying to find which team in my database has the highest coach-to-player ratio. I have created two views, A containing attributes player_name and team_name1 (1 added to end of attribute to avoid foreign key conflict) and B containing coach_name and team_name.

Ideally I want to select the team_name with the maximum ratio found by dividing

`select count(*) from A group by team_name`

and

`select count(*) from B group by team_name1`

I have used ASC, limit 1,0 before to achieve similar queries, but I am stuck on how to translate that syntax to this particular problem. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I am new to MySQL and just getting used to the ins and outs.

Here is additional information about my relations you may or may not need:

plays_for(team_name1, player_name) both attributes are primary keys

coaches_for(team_name,coach_name)both attributes are primary keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply divide them in a `SELECT` statemenst
Basicall you can use this, as long it givws back only one result

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            A
        GROUP BY team_name) / (SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            B
        GROUP BY team_name1)
```

To get all ratios of all teams you nne
SELECT team_name, countA/countB  as divided
FROM
(SELECT  team_name1,
COUNT(*) countA
FROM
A
GROUP BY team_name) t1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT team_name1,
COUNT(*) countB
FROM
B
GROUP BY team_name1) t2 ON t1.team_name1 = t2.team_name1
ORDER BY divided DESC

to get the highhest ratio with team name

```
SELECT team_name, countA/countB  as divided
FROM
(SELECT  team_name1,
            COUNT(*) countA
        FROM
            A
        GROUP BY team_name) t1
        INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT team_name1,
            COUNT(*) countB
        FROM
            B
        GROUP BY team_name1) t2 ON t1.team_name1 = t2.team_name1
ORDER BY divided DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Hi nbk, thank you for your response. How would I go about choosing the team name with maximum ratio using your proposed query? I am receiving an "ERROR 1242: Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: see the changed answer

Comment: Thank you so much, this query worked perfectly!